# Join and enrich data in one table by closest date BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table with data:

| clientId | revenue | orderId | order_date | w_date | w_source | w_campaign |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111111 | 100 | 00000001 | 2022-08-02 | null | null | null |
| 11111111 | 1000 | 00000002 | 2022-08-07 | null | null | null |
| 11111111 | 2000 | 00000003 | 2022-08-07 | null | null | null |
| 11111111 | null | null | null | 2022-07-27 | source_1 | campaign_2 |
| 11111111 | null | null | null | 2022-06-30 | source_2 | campaign_4 |
| 22222222 | 250 | 00000011 | 2022-08-15 | null | null | null |
| 22222222 | 500 | 00000015 | 2022-08-22 | null | null | null |
| 22222222 | 100 | 00000087 | 2022-08-25 | null | null | null |
| 22222222 | null | null | null | 2022-08-02 | source_4 | campaign_6 |
| 22222222 | null | null | null | 2022-08-18 | source_1 | campaign_9 |

And I want to get the result:

| clientId | revenue | orderId | order_date | w_date | w_source | w_campaign |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111111 | 100 | 00000001 | 2022-08-02 | 2022-07-27 | source_1 | campaign_2 |
| 11111111 | 1000 | 00000002 | 2022-08-07 | 2022-07-27 | source_1 | campaign_2 |
| 11111111 | 2000 | 00000003 | 2022-08-07 | 2022-07-27 | source_1 | campaign_2 |
| 22222222 | 250 | 00000011 | 2022-08-15 | 2022-08-02 | source_4 | campaign_6 |
| 22222222 | 500 | 00000015 | 2022-08-22 | 2022-08-18 | source_1 | campaign_9 |
| 22222222 | 100 | 00000087 | 2022-08-25 | 2022-08-18 | source_1 | campaign_9 |

And I don't understand how to properly merge such data:

I have only one value with clientId on which data can be joined

w_date must be less or equal order_date

w_source & w_campaign must be equal w_date as well

I tried to do it with JOIN or subquery with LAST_VALUE but it doesn't work but perhaps the desired query is too easy for that I hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use window function and the `over` statements. I defined a `get_last` window range.

The `last_value` returns the last entry in that column.  The `ignore nulls` only takes filled values in account and ignores the all null entries. By limiting the range, only the values before that date are considered.

```sql
With tbl as 
(Select 11111111 clientId,100 revenue,1 orderId,date("2022-08-02") order_date,null w_date,null w_source,null w_campaign
union all Select 11111111,1000,2,date("2022-08-07"),null,null,null
union all Select 11111111,2000,3,date("2022-08-07"),null,null,null
union all Select 11111111,null,null,null,date("2022-07-27"),"source_1","campaign_2"
union all Select 11111111,null,null,null,date("2022-06-30"),"source_2","campaign_4"
union all Select 22222222,250,11,date("2022-08-15"),null,null,null
union all Select 22222222,500,15,date("2022-08-22"),null,null,null
union all Select 22222222,100,87,date("2022-08-25"),null,null,null
union all Select 22222222,null,null,null,date("2022-08-02"),"source_4","campaign_6"
union all Select 22222222,null,null,null,date("2022-08-18"),"source_1","campaign_9"
),
tmp as 
(Select * except(w_date,w_source,w_campaign) ,
last_value(w_date ignore nulls) over get_last as w_date_,
last_value(w_source ignore nulls) over get_last as w_source_,
last_value(w_campaign ignore nulls) over get_last as w_campaign_,
from tbl
window get_last as (partition by clientid order by ifnull(order_date,w_date) range between unbounded preceding and current row )
) 
Select * from  tmp
where orderId is not null
```